# how to reference an alias in an oracle nested query?

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I have a couple of nested queries like this:

```
(SELECT "impartidas"."idUsuarioProf"
   FROM "impartidas"
   WHERE "impartidas"."periodo" = "periodoPlanGrado"."periodo" and
         "impartidas"."idMateria" = "materiasPlan"."idMateria") T,
(SELECT "usuarios"."apellidoPaterno" || ' , ' || "usuarios"."nombres"
   FROM "usuarios"
   WHERE "usuarios"."idUsuario" = 36) as "nomprofesor"
```

The first one outputs the `teacher ID` in a column named `T`.

What do I need to change in the second query, just so that instead of `36`, it uses the value that was shown in column aliased `T`?

In short I need to perform the second query, based on the output `ID` value of the first query.

Comment: The answer to your question is "by joining them together".  However, you should restructure the queries so all the tables are in each of them.  The first references three tables, but there is only one in the "from" clause.

Comment: as mentionned by @GordonLinoff , please provide a full example

Comment: @GordonLinoff makes a good point.  We really can't help you much as A) we don't know what your database looks like, B) the first query you provided has no chance of running, leading me to believe that C) you need to understand that this is not a "do my homework for me" site.  Edit your post, give us something that's close and shows some effort, and perhaps we can suggest some ideas for you to try.

Comment: My tip: lose the non-conventional table and column names. If you have to use double-quotes then you're going against a widely respected convention.

Comment: To David's comment: I agree, double quoted identifiers not only go against the convention but also introduce a lot of work and headache. And it would be good to use some short table aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

r In the absence of any context it's difficult to understand why you're taken such a convoluted approach.  The obvious approach is just a straightforward join:

```
SELECT "impartidas"."idUsuarioProf"    
 ,  "usuarios"."apellidoPaterno" || ' , ' || "usuarios"."nombres" "nomprofesor" 
FROM "impartidas"   
      , "periodoPlanGrado"
      , "materiasPlan"
      ,  "usuarios"
 WHERE "impartidas"."periodo" = "periodoPlanGrado"."periodo" 
and          "impartidas"."idMateria" = "materiasPlan"."idMateria") T
and "usuarios"."idUsuario" = "impartidas"."idUsuarioProf" 
/
```

But if you really need the inlining then you would need to do the joining externally, something like this:

```
select P."nomprofesor" 
from 
    (SELECT "impartidas"."idUsuarioProf"
      FROM "impartidas"   
              , "periodoPlanGrado"
              , "materiasPlan"               
     WHERE "impartidas"."periodo" = "periodoPlanGrado"."periodo" 
      and      "impartidas"."idMateria" = "materiasPlan"."idMateria") T, 
    (SELECT "usuarios"."apellidoPaterno" || ' , ' || "usuarios"."nombres"  as "nomprofesor" 
            , "usuarios"."idUsuario"
      FROM "usuarios"       ) P     
WHERE P."idUsuario" = T."idUsuarioProf"
```

Note that you need to include all the joining columns in the projection of each sub-query.  As, you need to use an aliases to reference a derived column in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT "usuarios"."apellidoPaterno" || ' , ' || "usuarios"."nombres" AS "nomprofesor"
FROM   "usuarios"
WHERE  "usuarios"."idUsuario" = (
           SELECT "impartidas"."idUsuarioProf"
           FROM   "impartidas", "periodoPlanGrando", "materiasPlan"
           WHERE  "impartidas"."periodo" = "periodoPlanGrado"."periodo" 
              AND "impartidas"."idMateria" = "materiasPlan"."idMateria"
        )
```

or maybe

```
SELECT "usuarios"."apellidoPaterno" || ' , ' || "usuarios"."nombres" AS "nomprofesor"
FROM   "usuarios"
WHERE  "usuarios"."idUsuario" IN (
           SELECT "impartidas"."idUsuarioProf"
           FROM   "impartidas", "periodoPlanGrando", "materiasPlan"
           WHERE  "impartidas"."periodo" = "periodoPlanGrado"."periodo" 
              AND "impartidas"."idMateria" = "materiasPlan"."idMateria"
        )
```

if multiple rows might be generated by the subquery (I do not know the schema and my Spanish is not very good (`IS NULL`) to understand what might be in the `"impartidas"` table).

For code maintenance and readability reasons I would write this:

```
SELECT u.apellidoPaterno || ' , ' || u.nombres AS nomprofesor
FROM   usuarios u
WHERE  u.idUsuario = (
           SELECT i.idUsuarioProf
           FROM   impartidas i
                  INNER JOIN periodoPlanGrando p USING ( periodo )
                  INNER JOIN materiasPlan m      USING ( idMateria )
        -- WHERE (other condifitions)
        )
```

or even this:

```
SELECT u.apellido_paterno || ' , ' || u.nombres AS nom_profesor
FROM   usuarios u
WHERE  u.id_usuario = (
           SELECT i.id_usuario_prof
           FROM   impartidas i
                  INNER JOIN periodo_plan_grado p USING ( periodo )
                  INNER JOIN materias_plan m      USING ( id_materia )
        -- WHERE (other condifitions)
        )
```

but this would require refractoring table and column names to be more Oracle identifier like.